# Como obtener el id de un objeto que acabo de registrar?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo un formulario para registrar un "Inmueble" en su respectiva tabla, pero quiero que al ser registrado, me redirija al formulario "Editar" (Tiene información adicional al formulario agregar, esta información adicional es hacia otra tabla, y una tabla relacional), pero para poder ir al Formulario "Editar" necesito el id del Inmueble que acabo de registrar, pero no se como obtenerlo.

Adicionalmente, quiero que redireccione al formulario de "Editar" una vez se oprima "Crear" de forma automatica. Pero no se como hacerlo, y que lleve el Id al mismo tiempo.

TABLA AGREGAR INMUEBLE

```
 <?php 
                if($_POST['rumbo'] == 'agregarInmu' &&!isset($_POST['crud'])) {
            ?>
                <!--Agregar Inmueble-->
                <div class="cajaContenido center  ph9  sm9  md9  lg6">
                    <h2 class="p1">Agregar Inmueble</h2>
                    <form method="POST">
                        <div class="p_5">
                            <input type="text" name="nomen" placeholder="Numero Inmueble" class="ph9  sm10  md10  lg10" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="p_5">
                            <input type="text" name="ubi" placeholder="Ubicacion" class="ph9  sm10  md10  lg10" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="p_5">
                            <input type="text" name="tipInmu" placeholder="Tipo Inmueble" class="ph9  sm10  md10  lg10" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="p_5">
                            <input type="text" name="area" placeholder="Area Inmueble" class="ph9  sm10  md10  lg10" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="p_5">
                            <input type="text" name="descr" placeholder="Descripcion" class="ph9  sm10  md10  lg10" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="p_5">
                            <input type="text" name="coef" placeholder="Coeficiente"  class="ph9  sm10  md10  lg10" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="p_5">
                            <input type="text" name="chiCat" placeholder="Chip Catastral" class="ph9  sm10  md10  lg10" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="p_5">
                            <input type="text" name="matInmo" placeholder="Matricula Inmobiliaria" class="ph9  sm10  md10  lg10" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="p_5">
                            <input class=" button  create" type="submit" value="Crear">
                            <input type="hidden" name="rumbo" value="agregarInmu">
                            <input type="hidden" name="crud" value="create">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <!--Logica Creacion de Inmueble-->
                <?php
                } else if ($_POST['rumbo']== 'agregarInmu' && $_POST['crud']=='create') {

                    $controlInmu = new ControladorInmueble();

                    $nuevoInmu = array('nomenclatura'=>$_POST['nomen'],'id_ubicacion'=>$_POST['ubi'],'id_tipo_inmueble'=>$_POST['tipInmu'],'area'=>$_POST['area'],'descripcion'=>$_POST['descr'],'coeficiente'=>$_POST['coef'],'chip_catastral'=>$_POST['chiCat'],'matri_inmo'=>$_POST['matInmo']);

                    $inmueble = $controlInmu->create($nuevoInmu);
                ?>
                    <div class="item  center  addsee">
                        <p>El inmueble <?= $_POST['nomen']?> se ha registrado Exitosamente!</p>
                    </div>
                    <?php $inmueble = $controlInmu->read();?>
        <!--Aqui es donde no se como conseguir el Id del inmueble-->            
        <form method="POST">
                        <input type="hidden" name="rumbo" value="editarInmu">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="">
                        <!--No se como hacer que el form lleve esta informacion de forma automatica, por eso puse un button-->
                        <button>Hola</button>
                    </form>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según yo aun se conserva en el $_POST, lo puedes sacar con $idInmueble = $_POST['nombre que le asignaste']; o igual lo puedes guardar en un mysqli_fetch_assoc(); y lo metes a una variable de sesión y ya lo puedes usar en todo el proyecto.